# Reporting Group missing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, reporting, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2013, And working on Win Form to create simple RDLC report. But unfortunately my toolbox is not showing reporting group in the menu. I have tried everything available over internet but it seem's they all doesn't work. My Visual studio is Professional 2013. Please help me how to add this reporting feature to my visual studio. It is also now showing in the ADD NEW ITEM dialog box.[image]

Comment: Where are all the people. Please help me in this matter. i can't find reports in my VS2013, Now also not available in newly installed VS2015 EXPRESS. Please help me find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open your rdlc report in design view. Below the report designer, you will see two columns **Row Groups** and **Column Groups**. Below the Row Groups you will see the report **Details** section. Right click on the **Details** and you should see options for grouping.